# How do I unlock/do a Falling Twirl?

Tags: spider-man-2

In *Spider-Man 2* (2004) for the GameCube, I accessed the Spidey Store and noticed an acrobatic move, Super Fly Spider Guy, available for purchase. In the description, it mentioned that I needed to press Ⓐ while doing a falling twirl. I did not find anything called a Falling Twirl available for purchase though. How can I unlock/do this Falling Twirl?

Comment: @Neon1024 As per [Arqade platform tagging policy](https://meta.arqade.com/a/4639/platform-tags-are-useless), platform tags are only for questions about the platform or games’ platform-specific interaction. If and when *Marvel's Spider-Man 2* gets released, it will have its own separate tag, so there's no need to tag this question with [nintendo-gamecube]. Tags should describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

The "Falling Twirl" is just running Spider-Man off of the top of a building without pushing anything. If you do this and then Press A as you are falling you should be able to perform the Super Fly Spider Guy.